# Extracting div's InnerHtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page, from where I need to extract the innerhtml of the div. For identifying div i have only class.

```
<div class="os-box unround">
:
:
:
</div>
```

I need to extract the innerhtml of the div having `class "os-box unround"`, assuming the page is coming from url http://abc.com/xyz.html using C# in the page load event.

```
**Input:**

<div class="os-box unround">

    <div class="os-list" id="os-list-6.1 x64">



    <div class="item-box">

        <p class="item-title"><a href="http://devid.info/en/p127116/Atheros+AR5B95+Wireless+Network+Adapter"><span class="mark">Atheros</span> AR5B95 Wireless <span class="mark">Network</span> <span class="mark">Adapter</span></a></p>

        <p class="item-vendor"><span>Vendor: </span>Atheros Communications Inc.</p>

        <p class="item-os"><span>Operating system: </span>Vista64 W7x64</p>

     <p class="item-date"><span>Driver Date: </span>2010-09-26</p> <p class="item-version"><span>Version: </span>8.0.0.372</p>     <p class="download"><a href="http://devid.info/p127116/Atheros+AR5B95+Wireless+Network+Adapter">Download</a></p>

    </div>



    <div class="adv-box">



    </div>



    <div class="item-box">

        <p class="item-title"><a href="http://devid.info/en/p145532/Atheros+AR5005G+Wireless+Network+Adapter"><span class="mark">Atheros</span> AR5005G Wireless <span class="mark">Network</span> <span class="mark">Adapter</span></a></p>

        <p class="item-vendor"><span>Vendor: </span>Atheros Communications Inc.</p>

        <p class="item-os"><span>Operating system: </span>Vista64 W7x64</p>

     <p class="item-date"><span>Driver Date: </span>2010-07-08</p> <p class="item-version"><span>Version: </span>9.0.0.222</p>     <p class="download"><a href="http://devid.info/p145532/Atheros+AR5005G+Wireless+Network+Adapter">Download</a></p>

    </div>





    <div class="item-box">

        <p class="item-title"><a href="http://devid.info/en/p134802/Atheros+AR5008X+Wireless+Network+Adapter"><span class="mark">Atheros</span> AR5008X Wireless <span class="mark">Network</span> <span class="mark">Adapter</span></a></p>

        <p class="item-vendor"><span>Vendor: </span>Atheros Communications Inc.</p>

        <p class="item-os"><span>Operating system: </span>Vista64 W7x64</p>

     <p class="item-date"><span>Driver Date: </span>2010-06-24</p> <p class="item-version"><span>Version: </span>9.0.0.208</p>     <p class="download"><a href="http://devid.info/p134802/Atheros+AR5008X+Wireless+Network+Adapter">Download</a></p>

    </div>

</div>
<div>
```

Some url, say  http://abc.com/xyz.html has such html from above said div. I want to read it and display on my own page, on its page load event.

Output;

string containing the inner html of the os-box unround div.

Comment: ehhh is this using javascript?

Comment: try [jQuery class selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: he didn't mention or tag this as jquery though

Comment: ... and you've tried what exactly?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data inside the div? Is this to happen when the page is first loaded? Can you please provide more information.

Comment: Your "update" seems to suggest you need it in more than just C#, though nothing else in your post says what that should be.

Comment: I really do not know what you mean with "I need C# for the same.", but based on the title of your question on how to get the inner html of the div you can either use jquery or classic javascript. jquery `$(".os-box unround").html();` will get you the inner html of the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)?  It will allow you to parse and query (with XPATH) a lot of the malformed HTML you find.

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you might use:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://abc.com/xyz.html");

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode div = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[@class=\"os-box unround\"]");
string contentYouWantedToDisplayOnYourOwnPage = div.InnerHtml;
```